# About \b{w} Syntax in Unicode Regular Expression Word Boundary

Tags: regex, unicode

[RL2.2](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#RL2.2) in [UTS #18](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/) describe the syntax `\b{w}` for Extended Grapheme Clusters of Word Boundary in Unicode regular expression , but I don't quite understand its different from `\b` syntax. In [UTS #18](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/), it says

> \b{w}. A Unicode word boundary. Note that this is different than \b alone, which corresponds to \w and \W. See Annex C: Compatibility Properties.

So what is the difference between the two syntax exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\b == \w\W
```

Where `\W =  [^A-Za-z0-9_]` => it only deals with asci alphanumeric while `\b{w}` deals with UNICODE charset (ie: a wider alphanumeric set).

You can see an example of [an emulation of \b{w} here](https://regex101.com/r/V1srOJ/1) compared to the [*usual* behavior](https://regex101.com/r/1lRlyq/1).

Comment: For example, `/p\b{w}/` would not match `"pä"`, but `/p\b/` does. (Although, at this moment, I do not know of a compliant regexp engine).

Comment: Hi @Amadan, it seems that your example is opposite to Thomas 's answer?  In his answer, it seems `\b{w}` will handle unicode so it will match `ä`?

Comment: I did write it wrong for a second, it should be correct now. `p` is a word character but ä is not, so `\b` matches between them. Both are Unicode word characters, so there is no Unicode word boundary between them, so `\b{w}` doesn't.

Comment: Besides, will `\b` or `\b{w}` be included in the matching result? It seems that in the example of `pä`, `\b` will match `p` because the language change after `p` so `p` is actually a word boundary?

Comment: @Amadan it seems that pcre have a `Unicode` option that makes the same thing

Comment: @Xiangyu.Wu `\b` behave like a lookaround, it's a 0 width assertion

Comment: So, for @Amadan example, in which input string is`pä`, the regex `p\b` will match `p` while `p\b{w}` will match nothing, and `ä\b` will match nothing while `ä\b{w}` will match `ä`. It that right?

Comment: @Xiangyu.Wu yes

Comment: pcre does have the capability of matching on a Unicode boundary AFAIK but it does not support this syntax: in all engines I know, `\b{w}` will match a the three characters `{w}` after a word character.